# dropzone js uploading files stuck at 100%

Tags: javascript, tomcat, servlets, web, dropzone

I am developing a Web application on Tomcat and I am using dropzonejs for client-side handling. Everything is working fine, but when I am uploading it on Amazon Elastic Beanstalks and try to upload something it shows me in the progress "100 | 500". It always stops at this point and gets cancelled after 20 more seconds.

Can't find the problem in the code ? It is working fine on localhost.

[Image of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC0CV.png)

```
Dropzone.myDropzone = false;

var size = 1;
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

    init : function() {
        var dropzone = this;
        var filetogive;
        var givename;
        var tochange;
        var overwrite = false;


        this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
            tochange = file.previewElement
                    .querySelector("[data-dz-name]");
            givename = file.name;
            console.log(givename);
            getDokumentNamen(givename);
            filetogive = file;
            console.log(file);
        });

        $("#overwritebtn").on("click", function() {
            overwrite = true;
            sendfile();
            $("#saveModal").modal("hide");
        });

    $("#uploadModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
        cleardropzone();
    });

        $("#modalinputbtn").on("click", function() {
            console.log("filetogive");
            givename = $("#modalinput").val();
            tochange.innerHTML = givename;
            dropzone.processFile(filetogive);
            $("#saveModal").modal("hide");
        });

        function sendfile() {
            console.log("sendingstatus");
            console.log(filetogive.status);
            if (filetogive.status != "error") {
                dropzone.processFile(filetogive);
            }

        }

        function cleardropzone(){
            dropzone.removeAllFiles();
        }

        this.on("renameFile", function(file) {
            alert("called renameFile");
        });

        this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
            console.log("sending called");
            formData.append("dateiname", givename);
            console.log("givename:"+givename);
            formData.append("overwrite", overwrite);
            overwrite = false;
        });

        this.on("success",function(file){
            console.log("success");
            refreshtables();
        });
        this.on("complete",function(file){
            console.log("complete");
            refreshtables();

        });
        this.on("uploadprogress",function(file,progress,bytesSent){
            console.log("progress: "+progress+" | "+bytesSent);
        });

        console.log("finished init");
    },
    maxFilesize : size,
    paramName : "pdffile",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    url : "UploadServlet",
    acceptedFiles : "application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,text/plain",
    parallelUploads : 1,
    autoQueue : false,
    autoProcessQueue : false,
    dictDefaultMessage : "Ziehe Dateien hierhin zum Hochladen",
    dictFallbackMessage : "Dieser Browser wird leider nicht unterstützt",
    dictFileTooBig : "Die Datei ist leider zu groß. Erlaubtes Maximum sind "+ size + " MB",
    dictInvalidFileType : "Dies ist leider der falsche Dateityp. Es werden nur .pdf,.doc,.docx und .txt Dateien unterstützt"
};
```

EDIT: changed title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem myself.
In fact the upload was working fine, but the Server - side code had a dead-lock, therefore the upload got stuck at 100% and couldn't reach the success or completed status. After 30 seconds the request gets automatically cancelled.

Comment: Could you possibly expand on this a bit more? What do you mean the server had a dead-lock? I am running into the very same issue, and can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Smaller uploads work just fine - but bigger uploads get stuck.

Comment: Same issue I have, smaller files upload fine but bigger file stuck at 100%